# how to solve a slowness bug on prestashop 1.7?

Tags: prestashop

I have a prestashop 1.7.7.0 store with php 7.2.

Since a change of theme we notice a slowdown of the site.

The host is at the max of these skills and never hassle with other prestashop on the same type of hosting.

We got feedback from debug mode but I can't translate the elements?

Knowing that this slowness is random throughout the day, the site is fast and very slow almost 1 minute to wait for a page to load?

THANKS for your suggestions.

https://hkboutik.fr/

We did some tests but without really understanding their results:

https://www.dareboost.com/fr/report/a_3608129f2da9b7901f2fbf776?reportIds=a_3608129f2da9b7901f2fbf776

https://www.webpagetest.org/result/210422_AiDcY2_eede913238389749cf531960f8b47042/1/performance_optimization/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop include a built-it profiler that should help you to spot when / where slowness happens (of course if this is not hosting / server related)

Have a check at how to enable PS profiler here:

```
https://doc.prestashop.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=51184700
```

(note that guide is for PS 1.6, but it works the same in PS 1.7)